# was my phone hacked?

Tags: motorola-droid-x

I look at my dashboard and saw activity in a town 4 hours away from me and everything Google on my phone is acting weird, I think my phone was hacked what can I do? I have it in safe mode now, but I don't know what to do to fix it. Like trying to sign into my gmail account it kept telling me my password was incorrect over and over and I know I was putting the correct password. So it kept asking me to recover my account, and when I will try to click on the link to recover the account the same screen kept popping up saying incorrect password, like over n over n over n over

Comment: "everything Google on my phone is acting weird" If you want a useful answer, you'll have to be more specific. You wouldn't expect a doctor to diagnose you from just "everything in my body is acting weird," would you?

Comment: @DanHulme everything in my body is acting weird. I think some of the stuff I installed in it today may be causing strange wake locks. Brightness seems broken too. It won't go above 'dim'. Also I seem to vibrate randomly and silent mode doesn't seem to work. Did I mess up the kernel? I was eating popcorn and may have eaten a few kernels as well. 

Answer (score 1):

As for being hacked, it is possible, but there could be a simple explanation. When using Mobile data, the actual interconnection point with the Internet or the servers handling the ip address assignment may be in a different physical location than you, resulting in your connections showing from a completely different town. Heck, with Verizon, I would frequently get a different state.

As for the login issue, have you tried logging in on a PC to verify and/or reset your password? You need to isolate if it is the phone or the account first. If it is definitely the phone, you can try clearing app data for all the Google Apps (it will wipe settings for those apps so you will need to reconfigure them later--data will be re-downloaded from Google.

Also, though I haven't seen any reports today, yesterday there were issues accessing some Google services including logging in. Just in case that is the issue.